# Programatically upload files given absolute paths on computer through browser

Tags: javascript, html, file, pdf

I need to make a feature that transfers a local pdf file over the internet to my API, given the absolute path in the file system.

So imagine I have a list of absolute paths to files on my computer, and I want to automatically upload them without opening them one by one in a input modal.

```
/Users/user/folder/folder/file_1.pdf
/Users/user/folder/folder/file_2.pdf
/Users/user/folder/folder/file_3.pdf
```

Is there a way to open them programmatically through my website and upload them to my server?
I know how to send the files if I open them through an input, but how do I programmatically open a file based on its absolute path?

Comment: Consider what would happen if you could do that with `/usual/path/to/accounting/software/database/file`.

Comment: You don't. That would be a huge security breach.

Comment: Yes, I understand the security issue, of course I have no wish to upload files without a user's consent. In this case the user has a list of where files are located, and does not want to manually open each file. Is there any solution to such an issue at all?